# centering a button in my menubar

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to align a button so that it stays in the center of my menu bar. The jsfiddle will show you what I mean.

this does not seem to work:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Here is the code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/420qk42v/1/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, vertical aligning is one of the tougher things to do in HTML/CSS, depending on the situation.

However, if you not want to use absolute heights and must have it vertically centered, you can always changed the display to table, instead of block: `display: table;`

I edited your original jsfiddle for [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/420qk42v/3/).

I added `/* Comments */` where I either added or changed CSS.

Answer (score 0):

save yourself some time and try to use bootstrap.

here is the css you can use :

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px; /* account for padding and border if not using box-sizing: border-box; */
}
```

but you can find a complete detailed solutions if you take a little time and go to this link :

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your handle class 
https://jsfiddle.net/420qk42v/2/

```
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .handle {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffe2e2;
  font-family: "century gothic";
  opacity: 0.9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;  /* this is the change */
  }
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: no. Andy provided a good solution that worked for me. Your solution centers the text "menu" and that is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with the vertical align and it works if you remove the absolute positioning on the menu button.

I also made a new div around the text "menu" and then set that to position absolute while setting the handle to align the text to the right - the button will only move the right.

---

**HTML**

```
</br>
</br>
</br>
<nav>
    <div>
        <div class="handle">
            <!--<div class="heading">MENU</div>-->
            <!-- Menu button if on mobile device -->
            <a class="menu">
                <span class="line"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.handle {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffe2e2;
    font-family: "century gothic";
    opacity: 0.9;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

/*added class for the menu - the heading text*/
.heading {
    /*This is commented out in the markup but is to keep the menu heading on the right*/
    position: absolute; 
}
.menu {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.9em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1.75em;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu:hover {
    /* background-image: linear-gradient(#e63d44,#c11a22);*/
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22);*/
}

.menu .line {
    background: rgb(184,184,184);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 rgb(184, 184, 184), 0 -5px 0 0 rgb(184, 184, 184);    
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 16px;
    content: " ";
    overflow: visible;
}

.menu:hover .line {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 rgb(255,255,255), 0 -5px 0 0 rgb(255,255,255);    
}
```

---

Js fiddle to test - https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/b7mgaasj/